# import .CSV file with PHP using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having a problem importing .CSV data into a `SQL` database. I'm trying to use `PDO` in my `PHP` file to accomplish this and I can't seem to figure this out.

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploadedfile'])) {   

    // get the csv file and open it up
    $file = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']; 
    $handle = fopen($file, "r"); 
    try { 
        // prepare for insertion
        $query_ip = $db->prepare('
                INSERT INTO projects (                                      
                    id, project_name, contact, pm, apm, 
                    est_start, est_end, trips, tasks, perc_complete, 
                    bcwp, actual, cpi, bcws, bac, 
                    comments, status, project_revenue, profit_margin, pm_perc, 
                    audited, account_id
                ) VALUES (
                    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                    ?, ?            
                )');                                         
        $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'");
        $query_ip->execute($data);
        $count = $query_ip->rowCount(); 
        fclose($handle);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }       

    echo 'Projects imported ' . $count . ' rows were affected';

} else {
    echo 'Could not import projects';
}
```

Now this works, *kind of*. It imports the data but as you may have guessed this is only inserting the first row of the .CSV file, which by the way is the column headers. So I need to skip the first row and loop through the rest of this .CSV file.

Obviously throwing me some code would solve this, but more than that I would like an explanation of how to do this properly with `PHP Data Objects (PDO)`. All the examples I've come across either have huge flaws or don't use `PDO`. Any and all help is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: So, your question is on how to read a file sequentially?

Comment: You only need a `while`. Throw away the first `$data = fgetcsv`. Then loop over the rest, and just run `->execute($data);`

Comment: If your code is adding the first row, then you have the PDO side working fine; it's just the input part that needs looking at. All you need to do for that is put your `fgetcsv` in a while loop; add a flag you can set to see if this is the first line, and that should do it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense more or less. I would just like tips on proper practices when doing this. Obviously this is missing all file validation checking, but that's not what I need. I just wanted to make sure I was on the right track. From the comments so far it looks like I'm just missing the while loop, is this correct?

Comment: @mario thank you, so this is the proper way to do this then? I'm just missing my while loop?

Comment: @andrewsi thank you, I will try this. Feel free to post a full answer for future readers. If it works I will be more than happy to accept it

Comment: If MySQL has read permissions to the uploaded file you use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: @i_me_mine - if you can use my comment to do this for yourself, then you can add and accept your own answer.

Comment: @andrewsi ok i will do that, I was just trying to give you the opportunity

Comment: @i_me_mine - thank you; I'm just happy to have been of help, really!

Comment: @andrewsi thanks! see my answer. If you have any suggestions on how to improve it please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments helped me come up with this answer. I used the following code

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploadedfile'])) {   

    // get the csv file and open it up
    $file = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']; 
    $handle = fopen($file, "r"); 
    try { 
        // prepare for insertion
        $query_ip = $db->prepare('
            INSERT INTO projects (                                      
                id, project_name, contact, pm, apm, 
                est_start, est_end, trips, tasks, perc_complete, 
                bcwp, actual, cpi, bcws, bac, 
                comments, status, project_revenue, profit_margin, pm_perc, 
                audited
            ) VALUES (
                ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                ?           
            )
        ');

        // unset the first line like this       
        fgets($handle);

        // created loop here
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
            $query_ip->execute($data);
        }       

        fclose($handle);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    echo 'Projects imported';

} else {
    echo 'Could not import projects';
}
```

I hope this helps future readers properly import their .CSV files using `PDO`. It should be noted this should **not** be used on a live server/site. This code has 0 protection against potentially harmful uploads.

Comment: About the only suggestion I'd make is to look at the parameters for `fgetcsv` - if you specify a length parameter, it'll only read in that many characters at a time, so if a line goes over that length, it'll get split into two fields. You can set this to a number that's going be longer than the longest line (so 1000 is fine, if your data is short); or you can omit it (which would also mean omitting the separator, too)

Answer (score 2):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/* Database connections */
$_host = 'localhost';
$_name = 'root';
$_password = 'root';
$_database = 'TEST';

/* ========= Variables =========== */

/**
 * Defines the name of the table where data is to be inserted
 */
$table = 'terms';

/**
 * Defines the name of the csv file which contains the data
 */
$file = 'terms.csv';

/* =========== PDO ================= */
try {
$link = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $_database . ';host=' . $_host . ';charset=utf8', $_name, $_password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    $link->exec("set names utf8");
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
}
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

/* ========= Load file content in an array ========== */
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}

/* ========= Insert Script ========== */
foreach ($csv as $i => $row) {
    insert($row, $table);
}

function insert($row, $table) {
    global $link;
    $sqlStr = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
    $data = array();
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $sqlStr .= $key . ' = :' . $key . ', ';
        $data[':' . $key] = $value;
    }
    $sql = rtrim($sqlStr, ', ');
    $query = $link->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($data);
}

echo "Done inserting data in $table table";
```